# Can i ignore UDP's lack of reliability features in a controlled environment?

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp

I'm in a situation where, logically, UDP would be the perfect choice (i need to be able to broadcast to hundreds of clients). This is in a very small and controlled environment (the whole network is over a few square metters, all devices are local, the network is way oversized with gigabit ethernet and switches everywhere).

Can i simply "ignore" all of the added reliability that needs to be tossed on udp (checking messages arrived, resending them etc) as those mostly apply where the is expected packet loss (the internet) or is it really suggested to handle udp as "may not arrive" even in such conditions?

I'm not asking for theorycrafting, really wondering if anyone could tell me from experience if i'm actually likely to have udp packets missing in such an environment or is it's going to be a really rare event as obviously sending things and assuming that worked is much simpler than handling all possible errors.

Comment: How many packets are you willing to loose in percent and how much cost does a lost packet cause?

Comment: @usr one packet every couple 100 000 would be pretty insignificant.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of stochastics. Even in small local networks, packet losses *will* occur. Maybe they have an absolute probability of 1e-10 in a normal usage scenario. Maybe more, maybe less.

So, now comes real-world experience: Network controllers and Operating systems do have a tough live, if used in high-throughput scenarios. Worse applies to switches. So, if you're near the capacity of your network infrastructure, or your computational power, losses become far more likely.

So, in the end it's just a question on how high up in the networking stack you want to deal with errors: If you don't want to risk your application failing in 1 in 1e6 cases, you will need to add some flow/data integrity control; which really isn't that hard. If you can live with the fact that the average program has to be restarted every once in a while, well, that's error correction on user level...

Generally, I'd encourage you to *not* take risks. CPU power is just too cheap, and bandwidth, too, in most cases. Try [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/), which has broadcast communication models, and will ensure data integrity (and resend stuff if necessary), is available for practically all relevant languages, and runs on all relevant OSes, and is (at least from my perspective) easier to use than raw UDP sockets.

Comment: I'm not far at all from the capacity of the network, it's barely going to be used at all. Using a third party native Library isn't Worth it either for me (it's going to be raw udp in .net / mono, software will be running on Windows 8 64 bit on one side and ARM linux on the other side, i really don't want to compile for linux at all and .net allows me to just use the same .exe on both platforms without any added dependencies). An error wouldn't cause a program crash/ restart it would simply include some data loss, it's ok if it's VERY occassional (once every few 100 000 packets or less).

Comment: It's not the CPU usage i'm afraid off, it's the added code complexity vs assuming "all went fine"

Comment: Well, then excuse me if I say: You seem to have a definite answer. However, using a library that does things right shouldn't be considered "adding code complexity". Actually, you'll find that proper communication models like ZeroMQ's publisher/subscriber model make development easier and debugging easier (and unecessary).

Also, you don't have to use a compiled language to work with ZeroMQ -- I use it from python all the time, and I'm audacious enough to claim that there are surely some example programs that just implement a shell-scriptable subscriber or something of the like.

Comment: Nonono, adding code complexity was NOT refering to the Library but to doing it myself. Adding the Library is out of the question for another reason. I'm not worried at consuming it from .net either as that's trivial but i'm worried about having to compile it myself for arm to run on the end devices and that's out of my knowledge set (they provide builds for Windows and linux as well as source but i don't see myself compiling it on linux on arm on a tiny device and figuring out how to install it and how to call it from mono as someone with 0 unix knowledge)

Comment: Well, you're writing some networking software for the ARM, aren't you? Why is using a library there a significant problem?

Comment: I'm not writing any software "for the arm" but "for .net", and .net is portable not only at the source but also at the binary level (you can take a .exe made on Windows 8 for X84 and run it as is on mono / linux / arm). I'm not compiling anything "for linux" nor compiling C++

Comment: I know, but that means that anything that has a portable implementation (like zeroMQ) will be as available on your windows machine as on the ARM; ZeroMQ has a [native C# port](http://zeromq.org/bindings:clr), ie. there would be MSIL bytecode after building it on windows. Really, if you install something as complex and with as many dependencies as Mono on your ARM, installing a specific library that most probably someone else (eg. your Linux distribution) compiled for that native platform can't be that hard either.

Comment: It's not a native port but a native binding aslas (if it was a port it would fill my need), i'd still need to get the native Library compiled and there. Getting mono on raspbian was just a 1 liner in the console

Comment: To cite:
> NetMQ
> Native C# port of ZeroMQ. Stable and actively maintained.

Comment: err, i actually kept reading and thought it was only 1 Library and not diferent ones on the same page, seems like this DOES solve my issues then, thanks!

Comment: After toying around with NetMQ i don't see a way to broadcast (as in udp broadcast to a network segment, not as in their xpub model of broadcasting to predefined nodes). Does this not exist in ZeroMQ or have i simply missed it?

Comment: There's the pub/sub model in ZeroMQ, which I *think* is what you actually want -- I can heartily recommend reading the zeroMQ intro, it's really short and concise on the [Publisher/subscriber paradigm](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out) -- and it even has C#/F# implementations of publisher and subscriber.

Comment: Pub / sub seems to be a one way model, i definately need bidirectional commands, maybe i should pub-sub for discovery and one way commands, and have the many end clients each connect to a dedicated req/rep ?

Comment: Pub/Sub works the other way around, too; you can have multiple publishers for a set of subscribers (which might contain only one subscriber, actually). Thus, your "server" could also have a sub socket for feedback (assuming this is all done asynchronously, and it's not something like "hey, all clients, here's a key, could you look into your database and tell me the value to that key", where you'd like to keep close order of requests and replies).

Comment: It's a bit of both, basically the use case is server broadcasts on a subnet to get a list of devices that reply. Then it may at any time send command 1 (start of a batch), then command X Y Z etc which are subsets of a batch, then command 2 which ends a batch and at that point it would like to receive data from all devices that is the result of the batch. In udp i was going to broadcast a list command and simply get a "ok" command from devices that reply, and then tell each of them i had a server listening on port X for device X port Y for device Y etc where they could reply when done.